# Read a file line by line and print lines with a variable length

Tags: php

I am trying to read a file line by line. Then print only the lines that match the variable length. If the $maxLength is set to 5, then print only the ones that are no more than 5 characters long.

I open the file. I know each line gets stored into the $output. How do I find the matching length? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if($handle)
{
  while (!feof($handle))
  {
    $output = fgets($handle, 4096);      
  }
}
```

Comment: Your course hasn't covered how to get the length of a string?

Comment: `strlen` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is the function you need to get the length - then subtract the length of the newline included by `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(is_file($file)) { $contents=file($file); }
for($i=0;$i<$maxlength;$i++) {
    echo($contents[$i]);
}
```

Comment: I see what the code is doing, but somehow it is not working out for me. BTW, each line is separated with a '%', so now I get bunch of '%' printed out.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. Sorry had a long day and could not think properly. @showerhead I didn't quite use what you recommended but thanks for pointing me close to the right direction.

Comment: As for the '%' you could just add a conditional in the loop to ignore them. As for why this isn't working I was reading your question wrong. Fixed the code in edit.